# Request resource not found when run Spring 4 controller on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I try to run a simple code but can't seem to get it to work and call the controller

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mypackage")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    /**
     * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript etc...
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```

This is my configuration file I then have a controller in com.mypackage as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class testControler {

    @Autowired
    AppDataService appDataService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public Model register(Model model){


        model.addAttribute("name", "Y");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(ModelMap model){

        Date start = new Date();
        System.out.println(start);
        List<AppData> app = appDataService.getListAppData();
        Date end = new Date();
        System.out.println(end);

        String result = "";
        for (Object a : app) {
            result+=a+" <br>";
        } 
        model.addAttribute("name", result);

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

and I have added the `hello.jsp`. When I run the project on the tomcat server through eclipse I don't get the `hello.jsp` but I get the resource not found, error **404**.
I am not sure what I am doing incorrect here as how I understand it I should be getting the start page hitting this controller because of the `@RequestMapping("/")` but I am not sure what is wrong or what goes wrong here.

I also have the  annotation version of the `web.xml` as follows:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Comment: What is in web.xml - servlet tags?

Comment: the web.xml file is empty

Comment: Move the `AppConfig` to the `getServletConfigClasses`.

Comment: @M.Deinum What do you mean?

Comment: Exactly as I say. You have specified the root config classes, which are loaded by the context loader listener. The `DispatcherServlet` for certain beans doesn't look at the parent hence doesn't find stuff. So move that to the method I mentioned.

Comment: @M.Deinum did not work

Answer (score 0):

1). Remove one more *`@RequestMapping("/")`* *above* the *`testControler`* class, because it produces double mapping since it's already there in `index()` method.

2). Modify your *`configureViewResolvers()`* to return *`ViewResolver`* object instead. 
Then you annotate it with `@Bean` :

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver configureViewResolvers() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver ;
    }
```

like so :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mypackage")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
   public ViewResolver configureViewResolvers() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver ;
    }

    /**
     * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript etc...
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```

Comment: did not change anything

Comment: put `hello.jsp` in the `views` folder under WEB-INF

Comment: also remove one more `@RequestMapping("/")` above the `testControler` class, because it produces double mapping since it's already there in *`index()`* method

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/", ".jsp");
}
```